# name/acronym/abbreviation explanation for hashes

Tags: hash, terminology

(Cryptographically and hash/checksum wise consider me a rookie, as I'm rather just using algorithms.) While there are many names, not all of them are explained - I tried searching for the meaning of a couple of names, but found neither an explanation in Wikipedia articles (multiple, like English, German and French), nor in published papers.

- [HAVAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAVAL) - its uppercase letters imply an acronym/abbreviation, not the [given name Haval](https://vornamen.blog/Haval).
- [Tiger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger_(hash_function)) shows on [Eli Biham' page](https://web.archive.org/web/20221009132547/https://www.cs.technion.ac.il/%7Ebiham/Reports/Tiger/) in the header a drawing of Winnie Pooh's [Tigger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tigger) although that character's name differs.
- [Panama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panama_(cryptography)) - its 3 syllables might be meant for the 3 modes *Push*, *Pull* and *Blank*...
- ["Square" (16 bytes digest size, 16 bytes block size)](https://github.com/MHumm/DelphiEncryptionCompendium/blob/master/Source/DECHash.pas#L4164) - is that even its official name, or just a plain "method", like the [Middle-square method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-square_method)?
- stream cipher [Sapphire](https://cryptography.org/mpj/sapphire.pdf)
- [BLAKE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAKE_(hash_function)) again comes in all uppercase - maybe an acronym or abbreviation?
- *CRC-32C* stands for **C**yclic **R**edundancy **C**heck **32**-bit [**C**astagnoli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#Standards_and_common_use), but what's this person's full name?

Is there a collection or compilation of hash and cipher names? F.e. for these names/abbreviations I found their complete meaning:

- SHA = [**S**ecure **H**ash **A**lgorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1)
- MD = [**M**essage **D**igest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5)
- RIPEMD = [**R**esearch and Development in Advanced Communications Technologies in Europe **I**ntegrity **P**rimitives **E**valuation **M**essage **D**igest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RIPEMD#History)
- Whirlpool = [**Whirlpool** Galaxy M51a](https://web.archive.org/web/20171129084214/http://www.larc.usp.br/%7Epbarreto/WhirlpoolPage.html)
- Snefru = [pharaoh **Snef**e**ru**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snefru_(Hashfunktion))
- Adler = [Mark **Adler**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adler-32)
- BJL3 = [**B**ob **J**enkins' **l**ookup**3**](https://github.com/dsapolska/dccontainers/blob/master/BJL/bjl3.pas#L3)